# On hover rotate images with interval - only affect the item hovered over

Tags: jquery

I have a simple image rotator - I'd like to use on multiple items on the page

Here's a simple fiddle showing the current non-working code.

Currently it causes all items to start rotating - how can I update my code to work only on the item being hovered over...

http://jsfiddle.net/tpt6kx3q/

(+ obligatory copy&paste to keep stack overflow happy...)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('.image-hover').hover(function () {

            flicker = setInterval(function () {
                if (jQuery('img.active').length > 0) {
                    jQuery('img.active').removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
                } else {
                    jQuery('img:first-child').addClass('active');
                }
            }, 500);
        }, function () {
            clearInterval(flicker);
            jQuery('img').removeClass('active');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Have you considered using jquery each - http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rotating images only for hovered element you should... rotate only this element images.

And two more things to fix:

- you have two non-closed `a` tags.
- elements IDs have to be unique. Use `class="flicker"` instead of `id="flicker"`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpt6kx3q/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var flicker = 0;    

    $('.image-hover').hover(function()
    {
        var thisEl = $(this);
        flicker = setInterval(function()
        {
            var activeImages = thisEl.find('img.active');
            if (activeImages.length > 0)
            {
                activeImages.removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
            }
            else
            {
                thisEl.find('img:first').addClass('active');
            }
        }, 500);
    },
    function()
    {
        clearInterval(flicker);
        $(this).find('img.active').removeClass('active');
    });  
});
```